# How to prevent `nesting`

Tags: javascript, android, nested

I made a code which works but my teacher told me i was ´nesting´ because he saw a lot of if/else statements, i tried shortening my code but i just don´t see how i can get rid of these if/else statements.

Here is my code, a short summary:
The code is a grid of nxn pieces and can only swap with the 'blank' tile so to do that my code looks as follow:

```
    grd.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // This statement prevents the player from playing the game
            // if the timer is counting down.
            if (timer == true) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "The game has not started yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else {
                clickcounter++;

                // Because difficulty's are 0,1,2 the row/column dimensions
                // are difficulty + 3, here i create the texview of the moves
                // as well.
                size = (int) difficulty + 3;
                TextView movesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                // Checks if click is even or odd. Even is firstclick odd is
                // secondclick
                if (clickcounter % 2 == 1) {
                    firstimg = (ImageView) view;
                    firstclick = position;
                    firsttag = (int) firstimg.getTag();

                } else if (clickcounter % 2 == 0) {
                    ImageView secondimg = (ImageView) view;
                    scndtag = (int) secondimg.getTag();

                    // To prevent cheaters to press twice on the same tile
                    // we set this if statement
                    if (position == firstclick) {
                        clickcounter = 1;                       

                    // Next we check whether one of the clicked images
                    // is the blank one, if that's not the case do
                    // nothing!
                    } else if (firsttag != crops.size() - 1
                            && scndtag != crops.size() - 1) {

                    // This else statements checks what happens if one has clicked the
                    // blank tile
                    } else {

                        // This statement below is the same as an switch/case statement
                        // but because of the fact that the switch/case statement gave the
                        // following error i chose for this method:
                        // case expressions must be constant expressions
                        int i = firstclick - position;
                        if (i == -1) {
                            if(firstclick % size == size - 1){

                            } else {
                                swap(firstclick,position);
                                moves++;
                                movesText.setText("Moves: " + moves);
                                checkwin2();
                            }
                        } else if (i == 1) {
                            if(firstclick % size == 0){

                            } else {
                                swap(firstclick,position);
                                moves++;
                                movesText.setText("Moves: " + moves);
                                checkwin2();
                            }
                        } else if (i == size) {
                            swap(firstclick,position);
                            moves++;
                            movesText.setText("Moves: " + moves);
                            checkwin2();
                        } else if (i == -size) {
                            swap(firstclick,position);
                            moves++;
                            movesText.setText("Moves: " + moves);
                            checkwin2();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I tried to make a switch/case statement to prevent this sum of if/else statements, but it said it couldn't identify size as a constant(because difficulty is a variable chosen by the player), so if i can manage to do that maybe the overload of if/else statements will dissapear.

Any suggestions? I already did some work to make the code more readable, the original looked like this:

```
    grd.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            if (timer == true) {
                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "The game has not started yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else {
                clickcounter++;

                // Because difficulty's are 0,1,2 the row/column dimensions
                // are difficulty + 3
                size = (int) difficulty + 3;
                TextView movesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                // Checks if click is even or odd. Even is firstclick odd is
                // secondclick
                if (clickcounter % 2 == 1) {
                    firstimg = (ImageView) view;
                    firstclick = position;
                    firsttag = (int) firstimg.getTag();

                } else if (clickcounter % 2 == 0) {
                    ImageView secondimg = (ImageView) view;
                    Bitmap swapImage = crops.get(position);
                    Integer swapID = ID.get(position);
                    scndtag = (int) secondimg.getTag();

                    // To prevent cheaters to press twice on the same tile
                    // we set this if statement
                    if (position == firstclick) {
                        clickcounter = 1;

                    // These next if/else if statements are a summation
                    // of all kinds of
                    // rules that need to be implemented in the game!

                    // First we check whether one of the clicked images
                    // is the blank one
                    } else if (firsttag != crops.size() - 1
                            && scndtag != crops.size() - 1) {

                    // Here we check if the tiles are neighbors of each
                    // other
                    } else if ((position - 1 != firstclick)
                            && (position + 1 != firstclick)
                            && (position + size) != firstclick
                            && ((position - size) != firstclick)) {

                    // Check when secondclick on the right of firstclick
                    } else if (position - 1 == firstclick) {

                        // This prevents the game to swap tiles on the
                        // edges, like
                        // starting from 0, 2 with 3.
                        if (position % size != 0) {
                            crops.set(position, crops.get(firstclick));
                            ID.set(position, ID.get(firstclick));
                            crops.set(firstclick, swapImage);
                            ID.set(firstclick, swapID);
                            moves++;
                            movesText.setText("Moves: " + moves);
                            checkwin2();
                        }

                    // Check when secondclick on the left of firstclick
                    } else if (position + 1 == firstclick) {
                        if (position % size != (size - 1)) {
                            crops.set(position, crops.get(firstclick));
                            ID.set(position, ID.get(firstclick));
                            crops.set(firstclick, swapImage);
                            ID.set(firstclick, swapID);
                            moves++;
                            movesText.setText("Moves: " + moves);
                            checkwin2();
                        }

                    // Check when secondclick is above first
                    } else if ((position + size) == firstclick) {
                        crops.set(position, crops.get(firstclick));
                        ID.set(position, ID.get(firstclick));
                        crops.set(firstclick, swapImage);
                        ID.set(firstclick, swapID);
                        moves++;
                        movesText.setText("Moves: " + moves);
                        checkwin2();

                    // Check when secondclick is above first
                    } else if ((position - size) == firstclick) {
                        crops.set(position, crops.get(firstclick));
                        ID.set(position, ID.get(firstclick));
                        crops.set(firstclick, swapImage);
                        ID.set(firstclick, swapID);
                        moves++;
                        movesText.setText("Moves: " + moves);
                        checkwin2();
                    }

                    // This useful command rebuilds the imageviews
                    grd.invalidateViews();
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
```

with kind regards,

Kees Til

Comment: you can always break your logic into multiple functions which will allow you to keep your code more readable.  I don't think your code has reached an absurd level of nesting but it's getting close

Comment: Sometimes nesting is necessary did your teacher say why he doesn't like this code or did he give you any suggestions as to what he wants?

Comment: @brso05 My code was first a lot larger because i did not make the 'swap' function for example, so this code is 'cleaner' than the original, but it still has a certain level of nesting like Shooky says. I'm trying to make new functions to make these code more readable but don't see how to procede.

Comment: @Shooky, is it smart to make a functions of the last if/else statements named possible-swaps or would that be confusing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the inherent problem with "too much nesting" is code maintenance. So, it is good practice to learn how to reduce it.

When you have nesting loops/if-else there are a few things you can do to try to eliminate it. Here are a few pointers:

1. If you see repeated patterns in your code, in your case something like this:

   swap(firstclick,position);
   moves++;
   movesText.setText("Moves: " + moves);
   checkwin2();

You should create a method. Then, if for any reason it changes, it's all in one place. Also, that allows you to separate "logic" (if-else) from procedure.

2. Your code is very "procedural" which is sometimes necessary, but defeats the benefits of object-oriented programming. To change this, consider creating an object to handle this. Make the "logic variables" like this:

   int i = firstclick - position;

and using this example, make "firstclick" and "position" into private object properties and create "getters" and "setters". Then perform the logic based on the get/set. This will allow you to focus on how the object" is impacted based on changes to it. Then, if you did step 1, you incorporate those methods into your new object.

3. Also, you can try to take your deepest nested logic, turn it into an "object" and then try to do the same with the next deepest, and so on. This can reveal patterns of logic that are not obvious while also helping to make your code easier to read and maintain.
4. Check your "flag" variables. Maybe they should be grouped into one or more objects. You may even use an object as a "flag" - but even flags can become two or more variables in your code instead of properly becoming a single object.

Notes: do not be "afraid" of small or simple objects with only one or two methods. Also, do not hesitate to have single line methods. What matters is that the actions (methods) and properties (variables) are placed in objects because they are *related*.